# Return records for 100 specific surnames

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a tuple, `l`, with 100 surnames. How can I do something like this in sqlite3:

```
l = ("Smith", "Murphy", "Owens", ...)
with sqlite3.connect("census.sqlite") as conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('select firstname, surname from census_data where surname in ?',(l,))
```

so that I can return all the records for the surnames contained in `l`.

Comment: that doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**:  return all the records for the surnames contained in a `tuple`

The core is, create a Query with as much bindings - `?` - as in the sequence.
The `[:-1]` is needed to exclude the last comma `...?,`.

- [SQL As Understood By SQLite - whereclause](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#whereclause)

  ```
  surnames = ("Smith", "Murphy", "Owens")
  bindings = '?,'*len(surnames)
  QUERY = "select firstname, surname from census_data where surname in ({});"
            .format(bindings[:-1])
  print(QUERY)
  # >>> select firstname, surname from census_data where surname in (?,?,?);
  cur.execute (QUERY, surnames)
  ```

***Tested with Python:3.5.3 - sqlite3:2.6.0***