# android sqlite delete arraylist

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

I am trying to pass in an ArrayList of values to a where clause in a delete statement in Sqlite for Android. This is what my code looks like:

```
int delete = dbHelper.delete("MyTable", "field1 IN ?", new String[] {myList.toString()});
```

I keep getting a Sqlite Exception being thrown with the output of

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE field1 IN ?
```

Does the parameter need to have parenthesis instead of brackets? Or am I doing something else wrong.

Comment: This one uses python but it should give you the idea about what you need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383351/9952196

Comment: @Shawn I replaced the brackets with parentheses and I am still getting a syntax error. Do I need to put quotation marks around each value in the list being passed in, like ("value1", "value2", etc.)

Comment: Brackets? Parenthesis? Huh? I think you missed the point completely. You have to build a query string with the appropriate number of parameters in the list of values used with `IN` that can then be bound to values. Just like that answer, except building it using java functions instead of python ones.

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes at the start and at the end of each list item:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    myList.set(i, "'" + myList.get(i) + "'");
}
```

Then create a comma separated string with all the values of the list:

```
String list = TextUtils.join(",", myList)
```

you will need this import:

```
import android.text.TextUtils
```

and then:

```
String where = "field1 IN (" + list + ")";
int delete = dbHelper.delete("MyTable", where, null);
```

Comment: Would there be an efficient way to add quotes to each value in the list since in my use case they are not numbers?

Comment: Don't include user-supplied values directly in a query string. That makes little Bobby Tables cry. See my comments on the question for the better approach.

Comment: So my parameter now looks like `('...', '...', etc)` and it is still failing to execute.

Comment: Debug and print the string `where` from my edited answer. Then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the arguments/values for the **IN** clause, should be a comma separated list of the values in parenthesises and additionally each value, if not numeric, enclosed in single quotes (*double quotes can be used BUT they are not recommended [see SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)*).

However what you were really doing wrong

along the lines of `WHERE field1 IN ('A','B','C')`

So you could use :-

```
boolean after_first_string = false;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("(");
for(String s: mylist) {
    if (after_first_string) {
        sb.append(",");

    }
    after_first_string = true;
    sb.append("'").append(s.replace("'","''")).append("'");
}
sb.append(")");

int delete = dbHelper.delete("MyTable", "field1 IN " + sb.toString(),null);
```

- Note that due to the arguments being enclosed to protect against SQL injection, passing ('A','B','C') as a single value would result in it being enclosed in single quotes and being treated as a single string value.

  - Hence the need to pass the entire WHERE clause (*in this case*) as the 2nd parameter and thus the 3rd parameter as NULL.
- The above, as it encloses the Strings offers protection against SQL injection.
- The replace method is used to double quote any single quote in the list of strings.

## Working example :-

### Code used

The example uses a basic database helper that includes a **delete** method that passes the 3 parameters to the **delete** convenience method, that is assumed closely replicates your **delete** method (so is basically just a wrapper) as per :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public static final String TBL_MYTABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String COL_MYTABLE_FIELD1 = "field1";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_MYTABLE + "(" +
                COL_MYTABLE_FIELD1 + " TEXT" +
                ")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insert(String field1) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_FIELD1,field1);
        return mDB.insert(TBL_MYTABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public int delete(String table, String whereclause, String[] whereargs) {
        return mDB.delete(table,whereclause,whereargs);
    }
}
```

The invoking activity :-

1. Instantiates the database helper as **dbhelper** (replicating what would be done in your code).
2. Adds some rows (deleting any existing rows) and then uses the suggested method.

   1. Note that the row with a single quote demonstrates the potential need to double single quote each single quote should any exist in the data.
3. builds the IN clause (including the enclosing the parenthesises).
4. Invokes the dbhelper object's **delete** method.

Logging some relevant aspects. The code is :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete(DBHelper.TBL_MYTABLE,null,null);
        dbHelper.insert("A");
        dbHelper.insert("B");
        dbHelper.insert("C");
        dbHelper.insert("D");
        dbHelper.insert("'");

        ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
        mylist.add("A");
        mylist.add("B");
        mylist.add("C");
        mylist.add("'");


        //String[] mylist = new String[]{"A","B","D","'"}; //<<<<<< String array works as well

        Log.d("ARRAYTOSTRING",mylist.toString());
        boolean after_first_string = false;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("(");
        for(String s: mylist) {
            if (after_first_string) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            after_first_string = true;
            sb.append("'").append(s.replace("'","''")).append("'");
        }
        sb.append(")");
        Log.d("WHEREINARG", "The WHERE IN clause will use " + sb.toString());

        int delete = dbHelper.delete("MyTable", "field1 IN " + sb.toString(),null);
        Log.d("DELETED","Rows deleted = " + String.valueOf(delete));
    }
}
```

### Result

```
04-03 10:33:46.019 1609-1609/? D/ARRAYTOSTRING: [A, B, C, ']
04-03 10:33:46.019 1609-1609/? D/WHEREINARG: The WHERE IN clause will use ('A','B','C','''')
04-03 10:33:46.023 1609-1609/? D/DELETED: Rows deleted = 4
```

i.e. 4 of the 5 rows, as wanted/expected, have been deleted. The **WHERE IN** argument, in it's entireity, being **('A','B','C','''')**

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("field1 in (");
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) sb.append("?,");
sb.replace(sb.length() - 1, sb.length(), ")");
db.myList("MyTable",sb.toString(), myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Query("DELETE  FROM TABLE  where userName=:userName)

int delete(String userName);